# Node generate image from DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, html2canvas, jsdom

I want to generate image or blob from DOM element on nodejs. Since node doesn't have DOM to handle I'm creating one from JSDOM. My initial plan was to use dom-to-image library but it spitting errors:

```
    (node:10384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.
    at XMLHttpRequest.open (/home/webdev/servers/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:480:15)
    at about:blank:2:5649
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at j (about:blank:2:5177)
(node:10384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:10384) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Second plan was to generate canvas by: html2canvas and save it as blob. That also failed by generating:

```
Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo
    at module.exports (/home/webdev/servers/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
    at /home/webdev/servers/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:579:7
    at about:blank:6:156607 undefined
Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)
    at module.exports (/home/webdev/servers/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
    at HTMLCanvasElementImpl.getContext (/home/webdev/servers/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLCanvasElement-impl.js:42:5)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.getContext (/home/webdev/servers/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/HTMLCanvasElement.js:41:47)
    at A.value (about:blank:6:43814)
    at new A (about:blank:6:134500)
    at about:blank:6:63123 undefined
(node:11033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scale' of null
(node:11033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11033) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

window.scrollTo can be overwritten but canvas is more tricky. There is all sorts of errors including canvas in JSDOM

Rolling fix for it:
https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/1964

Also I was thinking about using puppeteer as my Virtual DOM since it uses headless chrome but that seems overkill and also can generate errors because you're running separate browser. (I can't even run headless chrome because of errors mentioning no sandbox available).

My question is. Is it even possible to generate image from DOM on server side of nodejs framework?

Project information:

Node version - 10.11.0 
Framework - nestjs latest 
JSDOM - 12.2.0 
html2image - 1.0.0-alpha.12 
dom-to-image - 2.6.0

Comment: use this npm : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare-screenshot-selector

Comment: I just happened to stumble upon yours and one another question regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877121/export-dom-node-to-gif-with-gif-encoder-and-dom-to-image-libs so yes, it is possible. However, there are many limits for a DOM to be recreated and saved as image, therefor I suggest puppeteer if possible. It worth installing it correctly and using it.